# Replace string in every line with a search result using Vi/Vim

Tags: unix, vim, vi

I have a file that shows the output of `ls`

e.g.

```
/home/john/A_2014.jpg
/home/john/B_2014.jpg
/home/john/C_2014.jpg
/home/john/D_2014.jpg
```

now I want to use this output to write an insert script for mysql.
I achieved to enter at the beginning and the end of every line the necessary code so the file actually looks like:

```
INSERT INTO myimages (name,picture) values ('#name',LOAD_FILE('/home/john/A_2014.jpg'));
INSERT INTO myimages (name,picture) values ('#name',LOAD_FILE('/home/john/B_2014.jpg'));
INSERT INTO myimages (name,picture) values ('#name',LOAD_FILE('/home/john/C_2014.jpg'));
INSERT INTO myimages (name,picture) values ('#name',LOAD_FILE('/home/john/D_2014.jpg'));
```

Is there a way to substitute `#name` with the string that occurs before `_2014.jpg` so that the final output looks like

```
INSERT INTO myimages (name,picture) values ('A',LOAD_FILE('/home/john/A_2014.jpg'));
INSERT INTO myimages (name,picture) values ('B',LOAD_FILE('/home/john/B_2014.jpg'));
INSERT INTO myimages (name,picture) values ('C',LOAD_FILE('/home/john/C_2014.jpg'));
INSERT INTO myimages (name,picture) values ('D',LOAD_FILE('/home/john/D_2014.jpg'));
```

Unfortunately there are to many lines to do this by hand. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Before

```
/home/john/A_2014.jpg
/home/john/B_2014.jpg
/home/john/C_2014.jpg
/home/john/D_2014.jpg
```

#### Command

```
:%s@\v.*/([^/]+)_2014.*@...\1...&...@
```

#### After

```
...A.../home/john/A_2014.jpg...
...B.../home/john/B_2014.jpg...
...C.../home/john/C_2014.jpg...
...D.../home/john/D_2014.jpg...
```

As you can see:

- use `@` as delimiter
- use `\v` to make regex very magic
- use `(...)` to capture a group, then reference it as `\1`
- use `&` to reference entire matched line

Answer (score 1):

Building on kev's answer, which shows how to use a back-reference, you also need to limit the text which will get replaced if you want to replace the "name" text.

Example for the entire file (using your :

```
:%s@\v.*'\zs#name\ze'.*/([^/]+)_2014.*@\1@
```

The `\zs` sets the starting position for the match, and the `\ze` sets the ending position. This lets you limit what text gets replaced. As kev mentioned, `\1` in the replacement text refers to the text captured in the `(...)` group in the search pattern. The search pattern itself matches:

```
.*    - any text
'     - an opening literal single quote
#name - the literal text, #name
'     - the closing quote
.*    - any text again
/     - the final '/' in the line
(     - start capturing a backreference
[^/]+ - at least one non-slash character (matches A, B, etc.)
)     - end backreference capture
_2014 - matches this text literally
.*    - any other text
```

The replacement `\1` replaces the entire match with the captured backreference, but remember we limited the match using `\zs` and `\ze` to only be the #name string.

Answer (score 0):

A "macro + substitution" solution…

1. Put your cursor on the first line to edit, then record your macro in register `q`:

   ```
   qq
   0/_2<CR>
   yh
   :s/#name/<C-r>"<CR>
   q
   ```
2. Playback your macro:

   ```
   :+,$norm! @q<CR>
   ```